# Align headings nicely

Tags: tables, pdftex

I have this code which is the beginning part of a big table.

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXX}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|X|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Shaft Diameter} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Max Torque} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Outer Flange Diameter} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Flange Base Depth} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Inner Flange Diameter} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Flange Boss Depth} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Pitch Centre Diameter} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Number of Holes} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Hole Diameter} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Key Way Width} & \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Key Way Depth} \\
  \hline
```

However, even though the headings are wrapped, they aren't being displayed nicely. Anyway fix for that please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please turn your code fragment into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including the documentclass and all relevant packages that are needed to recreate your problem. Please also clarify on your desired alignment maybe by using a sketch.

Comment: What's the main document font size, and how wide is the textblock?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can accommodate those long headers in such narrow columns. Hyphenating them is not the solution, because they become utterly unreadable.

You *might* rotate the headers and make them smaller, but this is much of a “last resort”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}

\newcommand{\mh}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{%
    \makebox[0pt]{%
      \rotatebox[origin=cl]{90}{%
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}{@{}l}#1\end{tabular}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|*{11}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X|}}
\hline
  & \mh{Shaft Diameter} & \mh{Max Torque} & 
  \mh{Outer Flange \\ Diameter} & \mh{Flange Base \\ Depth} &
  \mh{Inner Flange \\ Diameter} & \mh{Flange Boss \\ Depth} &
  \mh{Pitch Centre \\ Diameter} & \mh{Number of Holes} &
  \mh{Hole Diameter} & \mh{Key Way Width} & \mh{Key Way Depth} \\
  \hline
a & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd go for an “indexed” format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\newcommand{\mh}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\mhd}[2]{\mbox{(#1): #2}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X*{11}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}}
\toprule
  & \mh{1} & \mh{2} & \mh{3} & \mh{4} & \mh{5} & \mh{6}
  & \mh{7} & \mh{8} & \mh{9} & \mh{10} & \mh{11} \\
\midrule
a & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
a & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
a & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
{\footnotesize\raggedright
\mhd{1}{Shaft Diameter};
\mhd{2}{Max Torque};
\mhd{3}{Outer Flange Diameter};
\mhd{4}{Flange Base Depth};
\mhd{5}{Inner Flange Diameter};
\mhd{6}{Flange Boss Depth};
\mhd{7}{Pitch Centre Diameter};
\mhd{8}{Number of Holes};
\mhd{9}{Hole Diameter};
\mhd{10}{Key Way Width};
\mhd{11}{Key Way Depth}.\\}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given that the table has a header column and eleven [11!] data columns, it's almost certainly necessary to typeset the table in *landscape format*. One way to do so is to employ a `sidewaystable` environment, provided by the `rotating` package, instead of a `table` environment.

Note that if you use the `X` column type for the data columns, it's not necessary to encase the header cells in `\multicolumn{1}{X|}{...}` "wrappers".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % choose an appropriate document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % select suitable page parameters
\usepackage[english]{babel} % load language-appropriate hyphenation patterns
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
  \begin{sidewaystable}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}      % default: 6pt
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{12}{C|}}
  \hline
                    & Shaft Diameter & 
  Max Torque        & Outer Flange Diameter & 
  Flange Base Depth & Inner Flange Diameter & 
  Flange Boss Depth & Pitch Centre Diameter & 
  Number of Holes   & Hole Diameter & 
  Key Way Width     & Key Way Depth \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```